# associate array constructor not found when compiling a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

When using a type that is already defined in a package as

```
Type ArrError Is Table Of Varchar2(20) Index By Binary_Integer;
```

and declaring it as following in a stored procedure

```
arr_error(1) := PKG_TEST.arrerror(p_error);
```

results in the following error `PLS-00222: no function with name 'ARRERROR' exists in this scope`. In the above statement `p_error` is of type `VARCHAR2`

When using a global type created using `CREATE TYPE` command this works fine.
using the above initialization in a `CREATE PROCEDURE` block.

Comment: Your global type can't be quite the same, you can't create a PL/SQL table type with `create type` (PLS-00355), so it might be helpful to show the equivalent that you have working. Your call doesn't really make sense though; you're referring to a type (`arrerror`) rather than an instance of that type, and `p_error` doesn't match the index-by data type. Please edit your question to explain what you are actually trying to do, and to show more context.

Comment: Is `ArrError arr_error := ArrError(p_error);` what you really want todo? Or `ArrError arr_error; arr_error(1) := p_error;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to initialize if you got `Index by ...`

```
declare
    TYPE ArrError IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (20) index by binary_integer;
    arr_error ArrError;

    p_error varchar2(20) := 'test';
    p_error2 varchar2(20) := 'test2';
begin
    arr_error(1) := p_error;
    arr_error(2) := p_error2;
    dbms_output.put_line('arr_error(1): ' || arr_error(1)); 
    dbms_output.put_line('arr_error(2): ' || arr_error(2)); 
end;
```

If you don't have `index by ...` you need to call the constructor:

```
declare
    TYPE ArrError IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (20);
    arr_error ArrError;

    p_error varchar2(20) := 'test';
    p_error2 varchar2(20) := 'test2';
begin
    -- Needed because of no 'Indexed by'. Or else you get a 'ORA-06531' not initialized..
    arr_error := ArrError(p_error); 
    arr_error.extend;

    arr_error(2) := p_error2;
    dbms_output.put_line('arr_error(1): ' || arr_error(1)); 
    dbms_output.put_line('arr_error(2): ' || arr_error(2)); 
end;
```